# Decoding base64String into UIImage in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, base64, decode

I have a base64String that I need to convert into a `UIImage()` and display in a `UIImageView`. I've been trying for hours to convert it, but I keep getting `nil` from `UIImage(data: data)`. When I `print(data)`it looks normal, but I can't decode it properly into an image. What's going on, and why is this code not working?

```
let base64String = "data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAAAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAQAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf88IjD/XUlU/2RRW/9GLzv/kouQ/6Sdn/84Hiz/RCs4/0QrOP82Gyn/Nhop/0UtOv9FLDr/OR8t/zYaKf85Hyz/ubO2////////////7+/v//////+6tbb/RS47/+bl5v/Py87/OR4s/0gxPf/z8/P/vrq8/1dFTv82Gin/a1xk//////+4s7f/hnuB//b29v/+/v7/SjdC/0EoNv/5+Pn/39zg/zgdK/9oWGD//////5OIjf9ELTn/Nhop/6CYnP//////X0xW/zYaKf/Cvb///////0czPv9AJzX/9vX2/+Dc3/86Hy7/lIqP//////9jUlr/OB0s/zYaKf+qpKb//////2ZSXf82Gin/zcbJ//////9RPkf/QCc1//X19f/c2Nv/Pyc0/8nGyP/8/Pz/RzA8/zYaKf82Gin/q6Wn//////9kUVv/Nhop/83Gyf//////UD1G/0AnNf/19fX/1NDT/0w4RP/5+fn/zcnL/zkfLf82Gin/Nhop/6ulp///////ZFFb/zYaKf/Nxsn//////1A9Rv9AJzX/8fDx//n4+f/U0NP//////6GYnP82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf+rpaf//////2RRW/82Gin/zcbJ//////9QPUb/QCc0//Dv7///////+vr6///////39vf/RzM//zYbKf82Gin/q6Wn//////9kUVv/Nhop/83Gyf//////UD1G/0AnNP/19PT/4N3e/0s0QP+HfIL//////5uRlv9HLzv/Nhop/6ylp///////ZFFb/zYaKf/Nxsn//////1A9Rv9AJzT/9fX1/9zZ2v85Hiz/VD9K//////+7tLf/VkJM/zYaKf+po6X//////2RRW/82Gin/xb3C//////9OPEX/QCc0//b19f/c2tr/OR4s/1I9SP//////t7Gz/1M/SP82Gin/joWJ//////98b3b/Ri47/9XS1P//////STI+/0MpNv/y8fH/6+np/3FfaP+poab//////46Dif9CKjf/Nhop/0c0P//39vf///////r6+///////pp+k/zYaKf9GLjr/8O/v//////////////////Dv7/9AKjb/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/UkBJ/7Osrv/DvsD/joSJ/zkhLv82Gin/PCIw/35wdv+GeH7/hHd8/39yef9HMT3/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/Nhop/zYaKf82Gin/AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//wAA//8AAP//AAD//w="


let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)

print(decodedData) // prints out fine

let image = UIImage(data: decodedData!) // keep getting nil here
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function for decode Base64 String to String

```
public func decodebase64(str : String) -> String{

  let decodedData     = NSData(base64EncodedString: str, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
let decodedString   = String(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
return decodedString!}
```

then use this function in this way

```
let newimage:String? = decodebase64(busimage)
    if (newimage?.characters.count != 0)
    {
        ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(newimage!) { (images, url) -> () in

            if (images != nil)
            {
                cell.compnylogo.image = images!
            }

        }
    }
```

here you have to just use. or drag and drop this swift file.
[Use this image Loader File this will help you](https://github.com/natelyman/SwiftImageLoader)